# Execution by Earthworm

Tags: biology

We are talking about those comrades who come out on wet autumn days - you're right, normal earthworms, [*Lumbricus terrestris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbricus_terrestris). Playing an important role in ecology, earthworms stand at the lower end of the food chain.

Your task is:

- to come up with a plausible execution method which

  - **employs earthworms**
  - is as gory, painful and gruesome as possible
  - can be executed (execute... erm... excuse the pun) using basic medieval technology.

Comment: One method per answer, so we can vote up the nastiest?

Answer (score 4):

The condemned is [scaphed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaphism) with earthworms.

This particular punishment (*sans* earthworms) dates back to long before the Middle Ages:

> *The Persians outvie all other barbarians in the horrid cruelty of
>   their punishments, employing tortures that are peculiarly terrible and
>   long-drawn, namely...*

The method consisted in

> imprisoning the victim between two matching hollowed trunks, half barrels, or rowing boats (hence the name 'scaphism', from the Greek word for *ship*).
> The space inside would be filled with insects and, during the following days, would also get filled with the victim's excretions. The victim would be force-fed to prevent starvation and dehydration; a horrible, lingering death would follow over a period of several days due to a mixture of gangrene and septic shock.
> According to historians, victims could take as long as seventeen days to die.

---

Something like that appears, if memory serves, in the second or third volume of the *Necroscope* series (I think *Bloodwars*), except with maggots instead of earthworms.

Comment: I think you should elaborate the method explained in the link in more detail. Not everyone knows how this is supposed to work and the link might get out-dated at some point. But perfect method